# How to align text in automatically generated SVG?

Tags: php, svg

I have project to convert data from CSV to graph in SVG. Graph has not strict size, because width and height are based on data gained from CSV (that is export from smartphone/tablet app IoTool).

To describe graph, I added some texts - that are partially based on data, too.

In image seen by browser, there is text (for example - there are another six lines of such descriptive text)

```
    Graph name: RR interval
```

that has code

```
<text x="0" y="170">
    Graph name:<tspan id="LineName">RR interval</tspan>
</text>
```

Problem is, that text should be aligned to the left side of graph without any space before text. And instead it, there is big space between left side of graph and text.

And if code is

```
<text x="0" y="170">
    Graph name:
    <tspan id="LineName">RR interval</tspan>
</text>
```

then big space is also between the first and the second part of text

```
    Graph name:    RR interval
```

like if element `text` would count with text-indent from source code. This behaviour is without regardless of which font family is used. I tested *generic* families `sans`, `sans-serif` and `monospace`.

And I don't know why this happens - and how to stick text back to left side of graph.

---

A bit shortened code of one generated svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.rg/2000/svg" xmlns:link="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="47887pt" height="1197pt" viewbox="0 0 191548 4788">

    <g>         
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="47887" height="1197" style="fill: #EFEFEF;"></rect>
    </g>    
    <g style="stroke-width: 0.5; stroke: #AAAAAA;">         
        <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1197"></line>
            <line x1="200" x2="200" y1="0" y2="1197"></line>
            <line x1="400" x2="400" y1="0" y2="1197"></line>
            <line x1="600" x2="600" y1="0" y2="1197"></line>
            ...
            <line x1="47200" x2="47200" y1="0" y2="1197"></line>
            <line x1="47400" x2="47400" y1="0" y2="1197"></line>
            <line x1="47600" x2="47600" y1="0" y2="1197"></line>
        </g>
        <g style="stroke-width: 0.5; stroke: #AAAAAA;">
            <line x1="0" x2="47887" y1="1197" y2="1197"></line>
            <line x1="0" x2="47887" y1="1097" y2="1097"></line>
            <line x1="0" x2="47887" y1="997" y2="997"></line>
            ...
            <line x1="0" x2="47887" y1="297" y2="297"></line>
            <line x1="0" x2="47887" y1="197" y2="197"></line>
            <line x1="0" x2="47887" y1="97" y2="97"></line>
        </g>
        <g font-size="170" style="font-family: monospace; fill: #005959;">  
            <text x="0" y="170">
                Graph name:
                <tspan id="LineName">RR interval</tspan>        
            </text>
            <text x="0" y="340">
                From time:
                <tspan id="StartTime">2017-09-04 20:10:31.941</tspan>       
            </text>
            ...
            <text x="0" y="1020">
                Minimum value:
                <tspan>722.656</tspan>  
            </text>
            <text x="0" y="1190">
                Maximum value:
                <tspan>1718.75</tspan>      
            </text>                 
        </g>
        <g width="47887" height="1197" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke: #000000; fill: none;">
            <polyline points="0,1055.008 205.4,1047.195 409.6,1027.664 ... 47686.8,958.328 47886.2,976.883 47886.2,988.601"></polyline>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have `xml:space="preserve"` defined in your SVG.

The default is to not preserve spaces, so you would have had to have added it yourself.  Check if you have that set and remove it.

Comment: Yes, I have (had, I deleted it after your answer). I prepared code of svg by code generated by one graphical editor that can export also into SVG. And there it was used. So, I thought that it is needed.